# Loopback - Bulk Insert with a lot of records

Tags: node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

Am currently running into memory usage issues when bulk inserting a lot of records. I'm attempting to grab data from an external API, format into an array which matches the structure of one of my tables, and then insert that using the create method on my model. Is there a loopback way to queue up records for insertion (so that they can be inserted in chunks) so I'm not killing my server? Would be great to not have to hack around with timers and such.

Postgres is my backend DB, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

How many columns are you inserting? Have you added indexes to any of them? If you're doing any upserts, indexes can speed up updates from minutes to seconds.

If the bottleneck is the node server, does the external api support pagination? If so, you can insert one page at a time and wait for a response from the database before inserting the next page of data.

Comment: Unfortunately no on the pagination - I would love to be able to filter down the results that I'm retrieving at one time, but it's not a very up-to-date API. Haven't added any indexes (wasn't aware that indexes would speed up inserts - thought they had more of an impact on reads). Will look into that.

Only inserting 5 or so columns - each of which do not have much data (very short strings or integers).

Comment: Indexes will slow down your inserts if you're not doing any reads before and just blindly inserting everything. You could copy everything from the API into a file, then use COPY - postGres has a guide on how to initially populate a database: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: Thanks - I'm thinking that for scalability, going the straight SQL route might be better (your COPY suggestion sounds like a good one).

Comment: From which API are you grabbing the data ? actually in gerneral pagination filters are called offset either you can use skip - limit filters